# Is there a way to compute the Kaplan-Meier mean for left censored data using lifelines in python?

Tags: python, survival, censoring, kaplan-meier

I am using the lifelines python package to fit Kaplan-Meirer models to left-censored environmental data.

I am computing the mean using lifelines.utils.restricted_mean_survival_time(m,t)

where m is my fit Kaplan-Meirer model and t is the upper limit of the survival time.

If I do not specify t, I get my mean = inf. How do I determine the appropriate t value for my left censored data?

Comment: You KM curve probably doesn't hit zero, so the correct answer for t=None (not specified,i.e. all time) is infinity. It's up to you to set a meaningful end point.